# When, if ever, does iOS remove an app's cache files?

Tags: ios, caching

My app creates and uses cache files in the app's Library/Caches directory. Does the OS ever manage/remove these files, for example, if the device runs very short on storage?

I've personally never seen it happen, but a customer's asking and I'd never thought of it before.

Thanks.

Comment: Just FYI, this is fairly simple to test on the simulator.  Just go into the simulated file system for the app and delete files, using Finder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

> On iOS 5.0 and later, the system may delete the Caches directory on rare occasions when the system is very low on disk space. This will never occur while an app is running. However, you should be aware that iTunes restore is not necessarily the only condition under which the Caches directory can be erased.

So it looks like cache files only get removed on a system restore or when the memory is extremely low, but never files that are on a currently running app.